# Determining super class for registered user types

Tags: qt

I am attempting to determine which classes are subclassed from several different types. For example, if E1 extends A, E2 extends A, and E3 extends B, I want to find all classes that are subclassed from A and return a list of the types E1 and E2. These types are registered with the QMetaSystem.

My first attempt was to iterate over the user declared types, instantiate it, and get the superClass name:

```
int type = QMetaType::User;
while( QMetaType::isRegistered(type) ) {
    QObject *o = (QObject*)QMetaType::construct(type);
    QString parent = o->metaObject()->superClass()->className();
}
```

This seemed like a bad idea when I wrote it and didn't expect it to work. Unsurprisingly, it segfaults when attempting to get the metaObject.

Is it possible to get the information I need from the QMetaType or is there another way of getting this information?

**Update**

The problem seems to be in trying to iterate over all the user types. Before I register my types, some Qt type seem to be getting registered before mine. Specifically, the two registered types are QPaintBufferCacheEntry (typeId = 256) and QPaintBufferCacheEntryV2 (typeId = 257). I can initialize the object just fine, but it crashes when I attempt to get the meta object, so I'm thinking the cast is illegal. I'm not quite sure where these are being registered because my code base is not doing it explicitly.

I took this to mean that it just wasn't safe to iterate over and construct each of the user types.

Comment: I made a small test with Qt 4.8 and don't get the extra registered types. I don't think you can know if a type can be cast to QObject, so the only idea I have is make a list of your types and iterate over that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct. This should give you the name of the parent class:

```
QObject *o = (QObject*)QMetaType::construct(type);
QString parent = o->metaObject()->superClass()->className();
```

For it to work, your classes must have been declared with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Type)` and registered with `qRegisterMetaType()`. This is the case as `QMetaType::isRegistered(type)` is true.

Your user defined classes must also inherits from QObject (directly or not) **and** have the [Q_OBJECT macro](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) in their definition. This could explain your segfault.

`superClass()` can also return 0 if there is no parent class, but here all your classes should at least inherit QObject.

There is also `QObject::inherits(const char * className)` to know if an object is of a class inheriting, even indirectly, from className.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I didn't even know about `inherits` member. Unfortunately, the problem is still there. I updated the original question with some more information.